# android: how to declare a IntentFilter with long press back button action?

Tags: android

dose anyone know how to declare a IntentFilter with long press back button action? I know there is a ACTION_SEARCH_LONG_PRESS option for long press search button, but not a corresponding one as ACTION_BACK_LONG_PRESS for back button. That means you can do:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH_LONG_PRESS);
```

but you can't do:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BACK_LONG_PRESS);
```

So how can I add an option ACTION_BACK_LONG_PRESS to make the second command valid? Or is there a alternative way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

> So how can I add an option ACTION_BACK_LONG_PRESS to make the second command valid?

You can't. The Android SDK does not expose a means of detecting this event from outside an app.

> Or is there a alternative way to implement this?

If your objective is to have an activity in the foreground detect a long-press of BACK, [you can handle that through `onKeyLongPress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyLongPress%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want to activate some service under any circumstance, even if under home screen, which means it will not be in a certain activity or app. I guess onKeyLongPress only works when you are in the app, when outside the app, it would work the other way. Is it right? Hope I am wrong.

Comment: @hexicn: "when outside the app, it would work the other way" -- there is no "the other way". What you want is not supported by Android. *Maybe* there will be a way that you can do this on a rooted device.

Comment: By "the other way" I mean if another app has implemented long press back action differently with onKeyLongPress, it will respond "the other way". Thanks for your reply though.